# iOS How to handle FCM while app is not running

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am developing iOS app and I am using push notification app. I want to signout user as he receives a fcm notification.

My app is working well in following conditions

- When app is foreground
- When app is in background

My app is not working in following condition:

- When user has killed app.

Here I want to mentioned the case.

**The case is when app is closed or not running at all and server sends the notification meanwhile, I can see that app is showing banner/notification and by clicking on it I can get my server data and make user logout. but the following  case is the one that i also so want to handle and that is**

- *When app is closed, and notification is arrived, but user opens up the app by clicking on app icon.*

> Now tell me in above given scenario, how to make user logout since I
>   am not able to read server data in any of
>   UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate delegated functions

**Note: I tried using content_available = true but it is not working also.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my point of view, the best solution is using silent push (as you tried using `content_available = true`)

If you tried that and nothing works as your expectation then let's try to use an api, when user opens up the app by clicking on app icon then you need to call this api to check whether this user is allowed to login or not. If yes then process as normal, if no then force that account to logout.

Comment: isnt there any other solution? that will be the last thing we can do

Comment: Afraid not unless your silent push works well and you can catch the signal from that to log user out

Comment: can you explain it a bit more

Comment: I used to be in your case (just different purpose, my scenario is not log user out), my solution is using silent push. I mean in case your silent push doesnt work or for any reason you can not read server data in any of UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate delegated functions so let's use an api as i mentioned above.

Comment: when you used silent push, did you got any method running code, even though the app was terminated?

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesnt work if app was terminated.

Comment: can I ask 1 last thing

Comment: how to set the category Id, I am working on some thing and that will be so clean thing instead of using the method we discussed earlier. I will share that to you too.

Comment: What do you mean about the category id? @A.s.ALI

Comment: when the app is not running at all, and server sends notification, I was receiving it. but it was not handled by my app, until and unless user click on the notification and then I can get the data which server sent me. 
so in case there was trouble when the notification arrives and user still opens up the app by clicking app icon. so in this case I handled it. 

so I was asking can I really get to know while my app is closed, that when user cleared up notification of my app. I mean before getting notification cleared the data must forward to my app, or at-least invoke it.

Comment: Sounds quite confused to me, could you tell me what are you going to do to handle your scenario for now?

Comment: I want that if my app is closed or terminated and user receives the FCM notification,and if user uses Clear button to clear the notification, I want that my app respond to that action

Comment: I am afraid that you cant, seems like you need to use an api to check the condition to log your user out. Or you include that logic to all of your apis, if the condition meets then throw an error code, your client code will handle that error code to log user out.